# How to retrieve the User info?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data `uid` in `User` table data but for a specific user , I have 2 users, and it seems that it grabs the 2 users uid but I want to grab with i speficy not both of them just one.
Thank You In advance

```
    let specificDatabase = Database.database().reference()

    specificDatabase.queryOrdered(byChild: "User/FirstName").queryEqual(toValue: "The user first name")

    specificDatabase.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapShot: DataSnapshot) in

        for child in snapShot.children {
            print(snapShot.key)
        }
    }
```

---

```
 Firebase Data Structure
"User" : {

"ez8sTAsqXTWfnuzizUXU69VS4qM2" : {
  "FirstName" : "other",
  "LastName" : "Martin",
  "uid" : "ez8sTAsqXTWfnuzizUXU69VS4qM2"
},
}
```

---

```
 "Data" : {
"ez8sTAsqXTWfnuzizUXU69VS4qM2" : {
  "-Ll7jUYg6BxRAhWPLskg" : {
    "Name" : "other Martin",
    "Data1" : "data"
  },
  "-Ll7jW_elQIPTLESwDYD" : {
    "Name" : "other Martin",
    "Data1" : "data "
  }
},
 }
```

Comment: Sounds to me like a database structure issue. If you are going to need that userID, is it not possible to hold on to a reference of the users UID so when it comes to making a query you can access that users details directly. The method you are using would be very inefficient particularly at scale.

Comment: Okay what is a good way to do it

Comment: Well that depends on the circumstance. For example, if your data is in a tableView, and you are using a struct to populat that tableView, then all you would have to do is makesure that the struct also has a: var uid: String property so when that tableview row is clicked you can simply access data.uid to get the userID of the row and mak a call to Firebase using that data. If you have access to that users Display Name, them you must have at some point in time, also got access to their uid. Again I can only tell so much without seeing the entire project.

Comment: I don’t use structure I got a custom to the classes and the. Display to the table view , can you show an example of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling Firebase to order each child node of the root by its `User/FirstName` property and then filter on that. Since the child nodes of the root don't have a property at that path, the query returns no results.

Instead you want to order/filter each child node of `/User` by its`FirstName` property, which you can do with:

```
let specificDatabase = Database.database().reference(withPath: "User")

specificDatabase.queryOrdered(byChild: "FirstName").queryEqual(toValue: "other")
```

Comment: Do you Know how to do this : tableview row is clicked you can simply access data.uid to get the userID of the row and make a call to Firebase using that data. If you have access to that users Display Name, them you must have at some point in time, also got access to their uid.

Comment: Hey what about the uid how can I grab that from the data section and then display all the content of it, also the uid does have a lot childByAutoId.

Comment: I wrote your code but it seems to grab all the user how can I specify for one